# Kerberos / SPNEGO and windows app

Tags: windows, kerberos, spnego

We are building a windows app that needs to support Kerberos authentication. This app uses a web-view as the UI. When the UI connects to the server, server responds with WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate. As a part of the SPNEGO flow, the client is supposed to connect to the KDC to request a Kerberos ticket. In a web-view is this something that is automatically taken care of by the web-view ? Are there any libraries available for windows apps that can be used so that client can connect to the KDC to get a ticket ?

Comment: What rendering engine is the HTML UI using?

Comment: IE web-view is used as the rendering engine

Comment: It will work out of the box with IE.